# implementing a shell in C

Tags: c, shell, unix, fork, pipe

im currently implementing a shell in C.
My problem arises when i try to run a command like this:

```
SHELL$: sort < txtFile | grep key
```

im running `sort < txtFile` in a process (child), and in the parent i.e `else if(pid > 0)` im running the other command to the right of the pipe.

The program runs fine, but it exits the infinite loop that i set up in main to keep receiving input from the user.

How could i solve this problem?

this is the code i have so far to deal with the pipe, i didnt include the code that i have to deal with the redirects:

c2p is the pipe i setup for this.

```
if(pid == 0)
{
  if( PIPE_FLAG )
    {   
        close(c2p[0]);
        if(dup2(c2p[1], STDOUT_FILENO) == -1){
            perror("dup2() failed");
            exit(2);
        }
    }

    /* Execute command */
    execvp(cmd_args[0], cmd_args);
    perror("exec failed 1. ");          /* return only when exec fails */
    exit(-1);

} 
else if(pid > 0)
{
  if(PIPE_FLAG)
    {
        close(c2p[1]);
        if(dup2(c2p[0], STDIN_FILENO) == -1){
            perror("dup2() failed");
            exit(-1);
        }
        execvp(nxt_args[0], nxt_args);
        perror("exec failed 2. ");          
        exit(-1);    
    }
}
else 
{ 
    /* error occurred */
    perror("fork failed");
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: @KerrekSB thanks for your feedback, but i'm trying to figure out what's going on with my code. Thanks a lot for the answer though

Comment: You are calling `exec` in both the parent and the child process, so the shell itself no longer exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm running `sort < txtFile` in the child process, and in the parent I'm running the command to the right of the pipe.

What happens to your shell process, then? The parent process is the shell. By running the right-side command in the parent process you're having it take over the shell's process. Remember that exec() replaces the current process.

You'll need to fork() twice, and execute the two sides of the pipe in the child processes. The parent must remain the shell, which will then wait() for the children to exit before presenting the next command prompt.

Comment: great!! thats the type of information i was looking for. So when you say i'll need to fork twice, it means that after i execute the first command = sort < txtFile, i should have a pid2 = fork() and then do if(pid2 == 0){ /*child*/ process the rest of the commands?}

Comment: Just write a function that takes a single pipeline stage command (ie, _either_ `sort<txtFile` _or_ `grep key`), and forks and execs it. Call this function once for each of the two stages in your pipeline.

Comment: @Useless could you elaborate a little bit more on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
/*  How shell works */
#include<stdio.h>

#include<unistd.h>

main (int argc, char **argv)
{

  if (argc < 2)
    {

      fprintf (stderr, "\nUsage: ./a.out cmd [options]...\n");

    }

  if (!fork ())
    {

      argv++;

      execvp (argv[0], argv);

    }

}
```